# VS 2010 Load Test Counter Sets Stuck

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I've created a VS 2010 load test. The test executes on a dedicated test agent which fires http posts at a couple of web servers.

After running the tests I realised that I needed to make a few changes to the counter sets that I'd assigned. Problem is, even though I've changed the counter sets and updated the Counter Set Mappings under the active run settings I'm still getting back results using the the counter sets from my 1st load test run.

Also, test tests run ok but I get lots of pop-up msg boxes saying "index was outside the bounds of the array"

Any ideas what I need to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rebooting the server, the counters reset.